# Is it possible to deliver cross-platform binaries of FreePascal using only one host OS?

Tags: cross-platform, cross-compiling, freepascal, binaries

I'm doing a little app that I want to distribute in different platforms, at least the 3 major ones.

Is it possible to use only Windows has the host OS to compile the binaries for Linux, Mac OS X and other supported platforms without resorting to virtual machines?

Or should I ask around in some community to help me compile on, well OS X, actually, since I can virtualize a Linux machine quite easy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is possible** to compile from one plateform to another, it is called ***cross-compilation***. You will find extensive informations at http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/buildfaq.pdf

The buildfaq above contains sample cross-compilation :

- from Windows to Linux,
- from FreeBSD to AMD64 Linux

The FPC download page contains :

- the i386-win32 to x86_64-win64 cross-compiler
- the i386-win32 to arm-wince cross-compiler

The FPC mailing lists are at http://www.freepascal.org/maillist.var 
You will find more informations about FPC at http://www.freepascal.org/moreinfo.var

Answer (score 1):

(I'm the author of the buildfaq document above)

There are some limitations. You can't target x86 from powerpc, because powerpc misses an "extended" type. But in generally it works.

I have generated a complete Lazarus for OS X on Windows.

Comment: Thanks MarcoV, I appreciate that. I'm not going to support powerpc, I think it's a bit outdated even if there are quite alot of them still around...

Answer (score 0):

I would virtualize Linux, as even if you can cross-compile, it means you're not testing the binaries on their native platforms. OS X is a trickier problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to compile from one platform to another. We have a Mac and use FPC quite often. If you need some help with compiling on a mac, drop me a message.

Comment: I sure wish I could drop you a message, but looks like you really don't answer on info@cnoc.nl

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply. I e-mailed you.

Comment: This is incorrect, I crosscompiled an entire Lazarus from win32 to Mac and back. Some combinations are not easy, let alone end-user ready, but it can be done mostly, except from (non-x86)->x86 due to extended use for REAL constants in the x86 codegenerator. Note that includes windows/x86_64 (aka Windows x64, 64-bit etc), since extended was marked deprecated in Windows/x86_64 apis.